# Why did my CMake project break after upgrading macOS?

Tags: c, macos, cmake, sdl-2

Upgrading to Ventura 13.6 from, I think, 13.5 changed something about how CMake works on my Macbook. I am curious about what changed. Before I had the following setup:

- a file `CMakeLists.txt` with contents

  ```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
  project(Test)
  find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED COMPONENTS SDL2)
  find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)
  add_executable(test test.c)
  target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2)
  target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE SDL2_image::SDL2_image)
  target_compile_options(test PRIVATE -g -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing)
  ```
- a file `test.c` with contents

  ```c
  #include<SDL_image.h>

  int main() {
      SDL_Surface* surface_tiles = IMG_Load("figure.png");
      return 1;
  }
  ```
- The `SDL2` and `SDL2_image` libraries placed in `/Library/Frameworks`

I was able to both compile and run the script before upgrading. After upgrading I can compile but I get a runtime linkage error:

```
dyld[5506]: Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2
  Referenced from: <86C3AED6-AC52-3493-826E-893EAD045543> path/to/executable
  Reason: tried: '/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2' (no such file)
Abort trap: 6
```

From my research and using the tool `otool -l executable` I have concluded that for some reason CMake does not set `@rpath` for the executable. I can run the program executable by doing `export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/`. Alternatively, I have found that if I change `CmakeLists.txt` to

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(Test)
include_directories("/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/Headers/")
include_directories("/Library/Frameworks/SDL2_image.framework/Versions/A/Headers/")
add_executable(test test.c)
target_link_libraries(
    test 
    PRIVATE 
    "/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2" 
    "/Library/Frameworks/SDL2_image.framework/Versions/A/SDL2_image"
)
target_compile_options(test PRIVATE -g -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing)
```

Then the resulting executable has correct `@rpath` and I can run it without setting an environment variable. Does anyone know what has happened? Did the new OSX version break CMake or was my original `CMakeLists.txt` wrong in some way?

Comment: If you revert to the original system, does it all work? If it does, do you need that update? Or, more precisely, do you need that update now? Is it possible the update has an error that may be corrected?

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to revert due to the computer being managed by a company and I have to regularly update. Otherwise, that would have been a great thing to try.

Comment: When you upgraded was `cmake` also upgraded? If so, you may want to build/install the prior version as a private copy (e.g. In `/usr/local` or under your home directory). Then, retry with the older version to see if that changes anything.

Comment: Cmake was not upgraded.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you just have to run configuration again after some system stuff moved / upgraded along with the system upgrade.

CMake *can* detect when reconfiguration is needed during an invocation of the generated buildsystem and automatically reconfigure before build- Ex. if a cache variable has been changed, or the CMake configuration has been changed, but I don't think this is one of the supported detection conditions. And there are things that are purposely cached and not checked again for performance reasons, such as results of find operations.

Comment: By configuration you mean to run `cmake path/to/source` from within the build directory? I tried this after having removed everything in the build directory and I still got the runtime error.

Comment: @Angelos yes, that's what I meant. I guess my answer is wrong then.